# Why do they add addition $\mathbb{E} (s_1^-)<\infty$ when they have $\{ s_n, \mathcal{F}_n,n\ge 1\}$ be a submartingale?

Tags: convergence-divergence, martingales, conditional-expectation

By definition, if $\{ s_n, \mathcal{F}_n,n\ge 1\}$ is a submartingale then $\mathbb{E} (|s_n|)<\infty$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$. But according to a arcticle, in a theorem, author add addition: $\mathbb{E} (s_1^-)<\infty$. I don't understand why they did it. This is content of that theorem:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears that the authors of this paper are using a somewhat relaxed definition of "submartingale". Can you give us a citation for the paper?

Comment: that article here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177700166

Comment: @John Dawkins local convergence of martingales and the law of large numbers by Y.S.Chow

Comment: The first paragraph of the introductory section of the paper contains the authors definition of "submartingale": $E(s_n^+)<\infty$ or $E(s_n^-)<\infty$, and $E(S_{n+1}|\mathscr F_n)\ge s_n$,  for each $n$. The condition on expectation of $s_n^\pm$ ensures that $E(s_n)$ is a well-defined element of $[-\infty,\infty]$ but does not insist that $E|s_n|$ be finite.

Comment: @John Dawkins Can I relax condition: $\mathbb{E} (s_1^-)$ if I use common definition of submartingale: $\mathbb{E} (|s_n|)<\infty$ for all $n$?